# How to get default value in radio button component?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have created a radio component but when clicked it does'nt show checked
here is the code

```
import React from 'react';
import classnames from 'classnames';

const RadioButton = (field) => {

  const inputClasses = classnames('form-group  has-feedback  ',{
    'has-error': field.meta.touched && field.meta.error,
  });
  console.log(field.input.value)
  return(
    <div className={inputClasses}>
        <label className="radio-inline custom-radio nowrap">
          <input
             type="radio"
             name={field.id}
             onClick={e => field.input.onChange(field.val)}
           />
        <span>{field.label}</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RadioButton;
```

here is the field:

```
                    <Field
                component={RadioButton}
                label ="Yes"
                name="person.gender"
                id="person.gender"
                val={true}
              />

              <Field
                component={RadioButton}
                label ="No"
                name="person.gender"
                id="person.gender"
                val={false}
              />
```

So, how to get default value that is the initial value?

Answer (score 0):

> i want to get default value

```html
<Field
  component={RadioButton}
  label ="No"
  name="court.lit"
  id="court.lit"
  val={field.val}
  defaultChecked={false}
/>
```

If you want to share the value from parent `Field` component you have to pass its value to the child. Then pass to `RadioButton` component.

```html
<input
  type="radio"
  name={field.id}
  value={field.val}
  onClick={e => field.input.onChange(field.val)}
/>
```

> but when clicked it does'nt show checked

You missed the `value` field

Comment: How can i get the initial value??

Comment: you don't get the initial value you set the initial value on the value attribute for the radio component.

Comment: @Tim: Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

When using the `redux-form` library (which I assume is the case given your use of `field.meta` and `field.input`), you generally want to follow this pattern:

```
<input
  {...field.input}
  // your fields here
/>
```

This way, the `onChange`, `value`, and other fields are set for you.